# Problems inserting &nbsp; with PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, xslt, plsql, whitespace, html-entities

I have the following script that I want to insert into a table, but I'm having some issues with it.

```
declare
    v_xslt9 varchar2(32767) := '<?xml version="1.0"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> <xsl:template name="Template"> <xsl:text>Kære </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="/nameValueMap/entry[string=''FIRST_NAME'']/string[2]"/> <xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="/nameValueMap/entry[string=''LAST_NAME'']/string[2]"/></xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>'
begin
    insert into XSLT values ('','Note',sysdate,v_xslt9,sysdate,'T','')
end;
```

The part of interest is the following

```
<xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
```

I'm using PL/SQL Developer and when I run the script above it recognises

```
&nbsp;
```

as an entity and I then have to type in what value I want in it. What I want is a simple whitespace within the XSL such that the first and last name will be separated. I've tried all suggestions from the following link: [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#How_does_one_disable_interactive_prompting_in_SQL.2APlus.3F) - I just cant get it to work. Either it fails when I try to insert or it fails when I extract the data.

Is there some easy way of inserting a whitespace in the XSL?

Comment: Seems like PL/SQL Developer sees that as a "script variable" much like SQL*Plus. Try running `SET DEFINE OFF` before running your script (that would at least fix the problem in SQL*Plus)

Comment: already tried that.. without luck :(

Comment: Then you need to look into the PL/SQL Developer manual...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [command window](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plscommand.html) instead of a SQL window to run scripts in PL/SQL Developer. To transform one kind of window into another type, just right-click anywhere in the window and select "Change Window to" => "Command Window".

Then run your script as in SQL*Plus -- in this case with `SET DEFINE OFF` as the first line.

Comment: this seems to work also, but then I cant use the "declare" bit as it will not run the script. It just keeps extending the script when I type something.

Comment: Use a forward slash `/` on a new empty line to end a `BEGIN...END` block (as in SQL*Plus).

Answer (score 10):

use

```
'<xsl:text>'||'&'||'nbsp;</xsl:text>'
```

it will solve problem everywhere and forever, and as well as for you - for every future user.

Just isolate the symbol

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:text>&&nbsp;</xsl:text>
```

From the PL/SQL Developer manual:

> If you wish to use an ampersand in the SQL text that should not be
>   interpreted as a substitution variable, use a double ampersand
>   instead.

Comment: I've tried this and it works. But I'm guessing this will only work in PL/SQL? - problem is that I need to deliver an SQL to someone else to run and I dont even know how they will run the SQL - so I need a solution that is "universal" if possible.

Comment: Yes, this would only work in PL/SQL Developer.  As far as I know there is no universal solution.  Every environment has its own quirks that will make this difficult.  This is why many people always use SQL*Plus for running anything - it's not always the best environment, but it's (almost) always available.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
'<xsl:text>'||unistr('\00A0')||'</xsl:text>'
```

This `unistr('\00A0')` function returns the Unicode `NO-BREAK SPACE`

Or, if you want the entity itself, you can try this:

```
'<xsl:text>'||chr(38)||'nbsp;</xsl:text>'
```

The `chr(38)` returns a literal ampersand without trying to prompt for input.